# Powershell Script to Move Files to new server by last access date

Tags: powershell

I'm new to Powershell.  I have 80 servers that I need to connect to and run a Pshell script on remotely to find files recursively in one share by last access date and move them to another \server\share for archiving purposes.  I also need the file creation, last accessed etc. timestamps to be preserved.

I would welcome any help please

thank you

Comment: What have you tried already? What worked or didn't work? Basically you're asking for someone to write code for you, but SO is meant to help people with **their** code.

Comment: With 80 servers, why not use [File Server Resource Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/fsrm/fsrm-overview) and have a look at [File Management Tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/fsrm/file-management-tasks)

Comment: Apologies Theothis is what I've done so far

Comment: $LastAccessDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-130) 
$files = Get-ChildItem 'C:\dump1' -Recurse | where {!$_.PsIsContainer} | where { $_.LastAccessTime -le $LastAccessDate} 
$files
$TargetPath = 'c:\dump2'
$directory = $TargetPath
if (!(Test-Path $directory))
{
New-Item -Path $directory -ItemType directory -Force
}


foreach ($file in $files)
{
$file | Move-Item -Destination $directory
}

Comment: this works for me on my local machine, the next stage I'm stuck with, running it from my machine remotely on other servers

Answer (score 0):

You need to test this **thoroughly** before actually using it on all 80 servers!

What you could do if you want to use PowerShell on this is to use `Invoke-Command` on the servers adding admin credentials so the script can both access the files to move as well as the destination Archive folder.

I would suggest using ROBOCOPY to do the heavy lifting:

```
$servers = 'Server1', 'Server2', 'Server3'  # etcetera
$cred    = Get-Credential -Message "Please supply admin credentials for archiving"
$scriptBlock = {
    $SourcePath = 'D:\StuffToArchive'            # this is the LOCAL path on the server
    $TargetPath = '\\NewServer\ArchiveShare'     # this is the REMOTE path to where the files should be moved
    $LogFile    = 'D:\ArchivedFiles.txt'         # write a textfile with all fie fullnames that are archived
    $DaysAgo    = 130

    # from a cmd box, type 'robocopy /?' to see all possible switches you might want to use
    # /MINAGE:days specifies the LastWriteTime
    # /MINLAD:days specifies the LastAccessDate
    robocopy $SourcePath $TargetPath /MOVE /MINLAD:$DaysAgo /COPYALL /E /FP /NP /XJ /XA:H /R:5 /W:5 /LOG+:$logFile
}

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $servers -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock -Credential $cred
```

If you want to do all using just PowerShell, try something like this:

```
$servers = 'Server1', 'Server2', 'Server3'  # etcetera
$cred    = Get-Credential -Message "Please supply admin credentials for archiving"
$scriptBlock = {
    $SourcePath = 'D:\StuffToArchive'            # this is the LOCAL path on the server
    $TargetPath = '\\NewServer\ArchiveShare'     # this is the REMOTE path to where the files should be moved
    $LogFile    = 'D:\ArchivedFiles.txt'         # write a textfile with all fie fullnames that are archived
    $refDate    = (Get-Date).AddDays(-130).Date  # the reference date set to midnight

    # set the ErrorActionPreference to Stop, so exceptions are caught in the catch block
    $OldErrorAction = $ErrorActionPreference
    $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

    # loop through the servers LOCAL path to find old files and move them to the remote archive
    Get-ChildItem -Path $SourcePath -File -Recurse | 
        Where-Object { $_.LastAccessTime -le $refDate } |
        ForEach-Object {
            try {
                $target = Join-Path -Path $TargetPath -ChildPath $_.DirectoryName.Substring($SourcePath.Length)
                # create the folder in the archive if not already exists
                $null = New-Item -Path $target -ItemType Directory -Force
                $_ | Move-Item -Destination $target -Force
                Add-Content -Path $LogFile -Value "File '$($_.FullName)' moved to '$target'"
            }
            catch {
                Add-Content -Path $LogFile -Value $_.Exception.Message
            }
        }

    $ErrorActionPreference = $OldErrorAction
}

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $servers -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock -Credential $cred
```

Comment: I think robocopy is a good solution, have always used to move files around servers, just thought maybe a better way via Poweshell.   I'm going to give both of your suggestions a go, yes, of course, obviously testing first, always test on my own server first.

thank you again
regards
Lynwen

Comment: Hi Theo, not successful as yet, I am running the script on the server where I want the files copied to e.g. \\FILEREPO\servername1
therefore set $SourcePath a share on remote server where to GET the files from
and $TargetPath to Share that is destination of files \\FILEREPO\servername1 (on Local)
$LogFile to C:\temp\tempfile.txt

Have tried both suggestions but files are not being copied.
when I run part of the script to list the files, then it returns the correct files to copy but the actually copy does not happen

any suggestions please?
Lynwen

Comment: @Cymraes Well. you may run this on the server that should receive the files, but bear in mind that `Invoke-Expression` lets the server(s) each run the **script block** themselves, so `$SourcePath` is the server's LOCAL path and `$TargetPath` is where the files should go **to** (for each of the servers that is a REMOTE path). What is local and what is remote should be seen from the server running the scriptblock, not from where you're running the main script.